# Using constants in React Components

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm trying to print something to console when a list item is clicked. But the list is defined as a constant outside of the component using it. Obviously the onclick/logItem here is not working. How would you go about this?

Strangely, it logs every list item to the console when the component mounts.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const LIST_ITEMS = require('./ListItems.json');

const myList = 
  LIST_ITEMS.data.Items.map((Item) => (
    <li key={Item.id} onClick={logItem(Item.name)}>
      {Item.name.toUpperCase()}
    </li>
  ))
;

function logItem(name){
  console.log(name);
}

class ItemList extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="item-list-wrapper">
        <h3>Select an Item</h3>
                <ul id="item-list">{myList}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a function to `onClick`, not the result of *calling* `logItem`:

```
onClick={() => logItem(Item.name)}
```